# Ulysses on macOS - share local content between user accounts [without iCloud]

Tags: macos, markdown

Does anybody know how to share local Ulysses content across Mac user accounts?

I can see the local content is not stored at a user-specific directory:
`~/Library/Containers/com.soulmen.ulysses3`

I have a Admin account and a Standard account.  I want to share all of my files between these accounts.  But when I open my Ulysses on my new Admin account, I cannot see or specify the location of local files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add external folders in the sidebar:

[image]

For your use case it's probably easiest to create a shared folder in `/Users/Shared` and use Unix permissions/ACL to give read/write access to all users in question.

Comment: Thanks!  Works nicely & both users can see all of markdown files.  I just had to `chown` the folder inside of the /Shared folder to ensure the user with less privilege was owner.